# PHP template lookup by current URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am looking to use some php pages I created as a template across multiple subdomain websites. I want to change minor things across each subdomain (what database is being used and some basic settings but this is not important). I do not want to copy over all files every time I want to create a new subdomain as this will be a pain when making updates. So I want to be able to push updates to my "live" site that acts as a template for all other sites.

This is my current testing layout
I have a "live" site that looks something like this:

-dashboard

-division

-division->lookup

Each of these directories have an index.php that I want included when the appropriate url is visited.

For each subdomain website, I currently have:

-.htaccess file

-errors (includes 404.php)

Within my .htaccess file, I have the 404 page as this 404.php page and that page looks like this:

```
if((@include "/var/www/live".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."/index.php") === false){
echo "DOES NOT EXIST";}
```

If the url you are trying to go to exists in "live" it includes it and it basically mirrors it.

This seems to work except for when I try a url that is more than 1 directory deep. For example, if I am trying to go to test.myurl.com/division/lookup I get Google's 404 page (This test.myurl.com page can’t be found).

I am feeling like there has to be an easier way to do this and I am doing this all wrong. Where can I look to do this better? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check if the file exists and should address the depth issue

```
<?php
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (is_file($filename)) {
    // file exists as requested
    require_once $filename;
    exit;
}
http_response_code(404); // may be unnecessary
?>
<!doctype html> ... <!-- 404 page content -->
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this is how it is commonly done in the industry? I am trying to do best practice but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this!

Comment: Most sites that involve subdomains are using frameworks - such as Symfony or a Content Management System like eZ Platform or a blog like Wordpress